# How to connect to cloud SQL from android studio?

Tags: java, android, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I want to connect to cloud SQL from Android studio. below is the code which I am using to make a connection. Do I require to do any proxy settings from cloud console? Do I need to install SQL on my PC or anything similar?

Also, so far I have written the code below and getting, No suitable driver found, error.

CODE:

```
    public void getDatafromSQL() {
    Log.d("GeoL", "getSQL");
    Connection connection;
    String query = "Some query";
    try {
        String databaseName = "databaseName";

        String instanceConnectionName = "instanceConnectionName";

        String jdbcUrl = String.format(
                "jdbc:mysql://google/%s?cloudSqlInstance=%s&"
                        + "socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory",
                databaseName,
                instanceConnectionName);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, user, password);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
        Log.d("GeoL", String.valueOf(resultSet));
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
07-28 16:55:22.881 11550-11550/com.example.pratyush.geofencing W/System.err: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://google/[databasename]?cloudSqlInstance=[instanceName]&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory
07-28 16:55:22.886 11550-11550/com.example.pratyush.geofencing W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:594)
07-28 16:55:22.886 11550-11550/com.example.pratyush.geofencing W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:219)
07-28 16:55:22.886 11550-11550/com.example.pratyush.geofencing W/System.err:     at com.example.pratyush.geofencing.Main2Activity.getDatafromSQL(Main2Activity.java:169)
07-28 16:55:22.886 11550-11550/com.example.pratyush.geofencing W/System.err:     at com.example.pratyush.geofencing.Main2Activity$1.onClick(Main2Activity.java:62)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you want to connect to an external MySQL Database via JDBC you have to import the corresponding JDBC Driver.

Please have a look at the following link: https://gist.github.com/cofearabi/5039135

This is an example for Android. The driver can be downloaded from the official MySQL homepage

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: so what did you change? Please post your changed code and/or configuration

Comment: i had not included the class.forname line. i added that now it says                         java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver                              with this line of code included and gives the same old driver not found exception without this line of code

Comment: so did you import the corresponding library into your project?

Comment: no i didnt import any library into the project.... i added the mysql....bin.jar file as environment variable

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create socket factory 'com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory' due to underlying exception:               ........at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)............at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance...........at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance